# Expand close as duplicate gold badge coverage?

Tags: feature-request, tags, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I have ability to close questions, tagged with `ios`, as duplicates without the need for voting, however there are other related `ios` tags (for example `ios7`, and `iphone*`) which I should be able to close as they are equivalent to `ios`.

How do I go about expanding my question-closing ability to cover these related tags?

I guess there would need to be some sort of tag hierarchy to do this automaticaly, where ios is the parent tag of `ios[2-8]`.

Comment: That was already discussed on Meta SE. Can't find the post right now though.